# How do I sign my own kernel modules to avoid tainting the kernel?

Tags: kernel, signature

I've made a kernel module, using [this tutorial](http://derekmolloy.ie/writing-a-linux-kernel-module-part-1-introduction/) as an example. It works, but on loading I get a warning in kernel log:

> gdt_get: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel

This looks pretty untidy, so I guess I have to sign my module.

So the question is, how do I do it in Ubuntu? Do I have to somehow rebuild the kernel with my new key to make it possible to sign my modules?